# arranging an array in ascending order

Tags: c++

I was tasked in school to create a program that arranges an array's values in ascending order. It's almost there but whenever i input **"44 55 66 22 33 11 77 99 88 66"** or any number it outputs

**-858993460,11,22,33,44,55,66,66,77,88,** or a negative number at the start

what the heck is happening to the first number? is there something I am missing?

I'm quite new to c++, I don't quite understand the problem here.
and if there are any tips I could use please tell them.

```
int num [10] = {};
int z;
cout << "please enter 10 numbers you want to sort: ";
cin >> num[0]>>num[1]>>num[2]>>num[3]>>num[4]>>num[5]>>num[6]>>num[7]>>num[8]>>num[9];

for (int l = 0; l < 10;l++)
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            if (num[a] > num[a + 1]) {
                z = num[a];
                num[a] = num[a + 1];
                num[a + 1] = z;
            }

        }
cout << "your number in ascending order is: ";
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    cout << num[a] << ",";
}


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Looks like you're going off the end of the array with `num[a+1]`.

Comment: As @FredLarson says. Perhaps change the inner loop to only go to `a < 9`. It looks like the "insertion sort" algorithm, I'm sure you can find plenty of good explanations online, or in your algorithms book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error):

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
```

When `a = 9`, `num[a + 1]` will be out-of-range.

The line should be:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and easy program to arrange numbers in ascending order

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "How many numbers you want to enter:\n";
    cin >> n;
    

    int array[n];

    //Introduce a loop which takes input from user multiple times 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter number "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    //Create a new array. It will store numbers in ascending order
    int newArray[n];


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //Initialize "a" to 0 in the first loop before the second loop starts.
        int a = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j] || (array[i] == array[j] && i > j))
            {
                a = a + 1;
            }
        }
        newArray[a] = array[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << newArray[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```